# How to test click event in a html file in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have this route defined in my app.

```
$stateProvider.state('Details', {
    url: '/c/:cId/cDetails/:cDId',
    templateUrl: 'cData/Details.html',
    controller: 'DetailsCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',        
    resolve: {
      Fields: function ($stateParams,DataFactory) {
        return DataFactory.getFields(keys);
      }
    }
  });
```

here is the html for Details.html

```
<div id="Details" ng-cloak >
<button open-dialog click="ctrl.onClose()"></button>
</div>
<directive-form></directive-form>
```

I want to write unit test to check whether the dialog opens on buttonclick if the form is dirty. The form is created by the directive directive-form.

I guess for this I need to compile the details.html. Am I right?

I am not sure how to compile the details.html file and call the onclick method. Is this possible?

Comment: i don't seem to understand, when you go the correct url, the template would automatically be loaded, and you can check the ng-click

Comment: I want to write unit test for this.

Answer (score 0):

This is untestable code.

To make it testable, move your `OpenDialogIfFormIsDirty()` method to a method in your DetailsCtrl. Then remove the `onclick` attribute and replace it with `ng-click="ctrl.openDialogIfFormIsDirty()"`.

This is just the first step. Now post some of the code for the DetailsCtrl and the openDialogIfFormIsDirty() method in your original question and we can see how to make it testable.

Comment: The click event is handled by another directive open-dialog.